# How to convert regular function to async/await function taken from a singleton pattern?

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, async-await

I copied the following design pattern from [dofactory.com](https://www.dofactory.com/javascript/design-patterns/singleton)
My question is how can I convert that to async/await?

```
var Singleton = (function () {
    var instance;

    function createInstance() {
        var object = new Object("I am the instance");
        return object;
    }

    return {
        getInstance: function () {
            if (!instance) {
                instance = createInstance();
            }
            return instance;
        }
    };
})();

function run() {

    var instance1 = Singleton.getInstance();
    var instance2 = Singleton.getInstance();

    console.log("Same instance? " + (instance1 === instance2));
}
```

Comment: I don't see Promises or callbacks. What do you mean by "convert to async/await"?

Comment: I just want to make the above code to use asyn/await because I'm going to use that pattern for my dabatase connection.
I have this code: `const user = await utils.executeRequest(dbConnection.getInstance(), request);` but it produces error at first run because it's not yet connected but I am already trying to retrieve a record without waiting the connection.

Comment: If `dbConnection.getInstance()` is already `async` then you probably just need to make the wrapping function (the function that has this line in it) `async` and do `utils.executeRequest(await dbConnection.getInstance(), request);`. Unfortunately, this kind of thing means all ancestor calls need to be `async`, at least up to the point where you no longer care about the return value.

Answer (score 1):

It probably goes something like this (it's hard to tell without your code for asynchronously creating the instance):

```js
const Singleton = (() => {
    let instance;

    const createInstance = async () => {
        // no need to `await` in here unless it's actually needed as part of
        // your singleton build process; return the object or the promise,
        // whichever you end up with.
        const object = new Object("I am the instance");

        return object;
    }

    return {
        getInstance: async () => {
            if(!instance) {
                // `createInstance()` always returns a promise because
                // it's async; store the promise; this only happens 
                // in the first call to `getInstance()`
                instance = createInstance();
            }

            // it doesn't matter that we're returning the promise
            // (resolved or not), chained promises are coalesced 
            // and the `await`s in `run()` will either wait for 
            // resolution or resolve immediately
            return instance;
        }
    };
})();

const run = async () => {
    // let instance1 = await Singleton.getInstance();
    // let instance2 = await Singleton.getInstance();
    // not a good way to test this, lets try something else

    let [instance1, instance2] = await Promise.all([
        Singleton.getInstance(),
        Singleton.getInstance(),
    ]);

    console.log("instance1:", instance1.toString());
    console.log("instance2:", instance2.toString());
    console.log("Same instance?", (instance1 === instance2));
};

run();
```